# Double Javascript Alert when ticking Community Wiki for self answer

Tags: bug, community-wiki, self-answer, instant-self-answer

I discovered this yesterday when i was making a Meta post on Anime and Manga.SE and i just did a test on Stack Overflow.SE's Meta and right here (after remembering i forgot to report it).

In Chrome When you go to *"Ask Question"* and tick "*Answer your own question*" then tick *"community wiki"* you get what i'm quite sure is a Javascript Alert box warning you about how by making a Community Wiki you remove explicit ownership of the answer, bla, bla, bla.

Regardless if you click *"Ok"* or *"Cancel"* it appears a second time. don't know if it occurs in any other browser. kinda minor but a bug is a bug and i would think there are some people are twitching uncontrollably because of it.